# Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<script>
            function percentShow(a,b) {

            if(b==5){
                alert(b); 
                alert(document.getElementById('mydiv1'));
                document.getElementById('mydiv1').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

              document.getElementById('mydiv1').style.width = '50%';

            }


        }
        </script>
<?php 
   echo '<script>window.onload=percentShow('."'".$this->commonmodel->percentCount(5)."'".',5);</script>';?>
```

Comment: Too many quotes when passing parameters.

Comment: script is not working onload in php tag.it is returning null id...but on click it is working perfectly

Comment: HAve you got an element with an id `mydiv1` ?

Comment: <div id="mydiv1" class="rate_recei_slider ratingslider" style="" >
                            <div  style=""></div>
                      </div>......this is div

Comment: Maybe you should try to explain in your post what is wrong, what you want to achieve, what you have tried etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be your div not loading before script call try

```
<script>
function percentShow(a, b) {
    if (b == 5) {
      document.getElementById('mydiv1').style.background = 'blue';
      document.getElementById('mydiv1').style.width = '50%';
    }
}
</script>

<div style="height:50px; width:50px;" id="mydiv1">rgdfghdfjhfgj</div>

<?php 
   echo '<script>window.onload=percentShow('.$this->commonmodel->percentCount(5).',5);</script>';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your problem is, but I think you get the message that you "cannot read property 'style' of null". So I'm going to read your question as "how come I get this error message?"

The method `getElementById` is going to get the element from the document with that given id (as the name clearly states), but if it can't find the element, it will return 'null'. But null is not an object that has any methods or properties. So if you then try to call `.style` on that object, it will not work and crash.

Comment: Agreed, it's not finding the element(mydiv1) called by the script.

Comment: That means that between the time you initialized the document, and you clicked the button; the element was added to document. Make sure that the element is available before you call that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function percentShow(a, b) {
        if (b == 5) {
            alert(b);
            $('#mydiv1').css('background-color','blue').css('width','50%');

        }
    }
    </script>
    <?php echo '<script>window.onload=percentShow('.$this->commonmodel->percentCount(5).',5);</script>';?>
    <input type="button" onclick="percentShow(1,5);" value="test">
```